# I am using sqlite for testng in hyn tenant laravel. How to resolve this error?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, unit-testing

Target [Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Database\PasswordGenerator] is not instantiable while building [Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that Laravel's service container is trying to instantiate a class (`Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection`) that depends on an interface (`Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Database\PasswordGenerator`) which cannot be resolved by the container.

To resolve this error, you need to register a concrete implementation of the `Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Database\PasswordGenerator` interface in the service container. You can do this by adding a binding to your Laravel application's `AppServiceProvider` class or in a service provider that is specific to your Tenancy package.

Here is an example of how to bind a concrete implementation of the `PasswordGenerator` interface in the `AppServiceProvider`:

use Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Database\PasswordGenerator;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Database\PasswordGenerator\Hash;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind(PasswordGenerator::class, Hash::class);

}
```

}

In this example, we are binding the `Hash` class as the concrete implementation for the `PasswordGenerator` interface. You can use a different implementation depending on your needs.

After adding this binding, the container should be able to resolve the `PasswordGenerator` interface when instantiating the `Connection` class, and the error should be resolved.